# Swift full screen issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have question about full screen. When I open my app home page appear full screen but when I change page, incoming page does not open in full screen. When I hold the page and push it down, it goes back to the old page. It's not like the page opens. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new default behavior for modal presentations on iOS 13. Set your modal presentation style to `.fullScreen` if you want the pre iOS 13 behavior on iOS 13.

Comment: This is not working for me. Using Xcode 11.3.1.